# Rebooting Windows 7 in VirtualBox after Windows Updates hangs

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-update

I installed Windows 7 Enterprise 32 bit with VirtualBox.  The install went great.  Now I'm trying to install the Windows Updates and when I do the suggested reboot from the Windows Updates applet it just hangs on the "Starting Windows" screen.  It's done it at least 5 times now, as I experiment with which windows updates to install.  I've tried with 80 updates, with 1 update, and with a few other variations.  Any ideas on what to look for or try?

My host OS is Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit.  VirtualBox is version 4.0.8 r 71778

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend installing any of the hardware updates from Windows Update, you may also want to reinstall Windows 7 Enterprise and then install SP1 first, then install the other 20 to 30 one by one, each time you install an update windows creates a system restore point so you could try going back.

Comment: You're right, I should've just gone straight to install SP1.  I was able to Power off the machine and it came up clean after the hang, so I don't know for sure what the problem was, but I'll mark this as accepted for the SP1 idea.

Comment: Did it work for you?